# UITableView issue when using separate delegate/dataSource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**General Description:**

To start with what works, I have a `UITableView` which has been placed onto an Xcode-generated view using Interface Builder.  The view's File Owner is set to an Xcode-generated subclass of `UIViewController`.  To this subclass I have added working implementations of `numberOfSectionsInTableView: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and the Table View's `dataSource` and `delegate` are connected to this class via the File Owner in Interface Builder.

The above configuration works with no problems.  The issue occurs when I want to move this Table View's `dataSource` and `delegate`-implementations out to a separate class, most likely because there are other controls on the View besides the Table View and I'd like to move the Table View-related code out to its own class.  To accomplish this, I try the following:

- Create a new subclass of `UITableViewController` in Xcode
- Move the known-good implementations of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to the new subclass
- Drag a `UITableViewController` to the top level of the  *existing* XIB in InterfaceBuilder, delete the `UIView`/`UITableView` that are automatically created for this `UITableViewController`, then set the `UITableViewController`'s class to match the new subclass
- Remove the previously-working `UITableView`'s existing `dataSource` and `delegate` connections and connect them to the new `UITableViewController`

When complete, I do not have a working `UITableView`.  I end up with one of three outcomes which can seemingly happen at random:

- When the `UITableView` loads, I get a runtime error indicating I am sending `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to an object which does not recognize it
- When the `UITableView` loads, the project breaks into the debugger without error
- There is no error, but the `UITableView` does not appear

With some debugging and having created a basic project just to reproduce this issue, I am usually seeing the 3rd option above (no error but no visible table view).  I added some NSLog calls and found that although `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` are both getting called, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not.  I am convinced I'm missing something really simple and was hoping the answer may be obvious to someone with more experience than I have.  If this doesn't turn out to be an easy answer I would be happy to update with some code or a sample project.  Thanks for your time!

**Complete steps to reproduce:**

- Create a new iPhone OS, View-Based Application in Xcode and call it `TableTest`
- Open `TableTestViewController.xib` in Interface Builder and drag a `UITableView` onto the provided view surface.
- Connect the `UITableView`'s `dataSource` and `delegate`-outlets to File's Owner, which should already represent the `TableTestViewController`-class.  Save your changes
- Back in Xcode, add the following code to `TableTestViewController.m:`

---

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Returning num sections");
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Returning num rows");
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Trying to return cell");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text = @"Hello";
    NSLog(@"Returning cell");
    return cell;
}
```

- Build and Go, and you should see the word `Hello` appear in the `UITableView`
- Now to attempt to move this `UITableView`'s logic out to a separate class, first create a new file in Xcode, choosing `UITableViewController` subclass and calling the class `TableTestTableViewController`
- Remove the above code snippet from `TableTestViewController.m` and place it into `TableTestTableViewController.m`, replacing the default implementation of these three methods with ours.
- Back in Interface Builder within the same `TableTestViewController.xib`-file, drag a `UITableViewController` into the main IB window and delete the new `UITableView` object that automatically came with it
- Set the class for this new `UITableViewController` to `TableTestTableViewController`
- Remove the `dataSource` and `delegate` bindings from the existing, previously-working `UITableView` and reconnect the same two bindings to the new `TableTestTableViewController` we created.
- Save changes, Build and Go, and if you're getting the results I'm getting, note the `UITableView` no longer functions properly

**Solution:**
With some more troubleshooting and some assistance from the [iPhone Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/5453), I've documented a solution!  The main `UIViewController` subclass of the project needs an outlet pointing to the `UITableViewController` instance.  To accomplish this, simply add the following to the primary view's header (`TableTestViewController.h`):

```
#import "TableTestTableViewController.h"
```

and

```
IBOutlet TableTestTableViewController *myTableViewController;
```

Then, in Interface Builder, connect the new outlet from File's Owner to `TableTestTableViewController` in the main IB window.  No changes are necessary in the UI part of the XIB.  Simply having this outlet in place, even though no user code directly uses it, resolves the problem completely.  Thanks to those who've helped and credit goes to BaldEagle on the iPhone Developer Forums for finding the solution.

Comment: Can you provide the source of these solutions? I can't follow up with those........ yet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I followed your steps, recreated the project and ran into the same problem. Basically you are almost there. There are 2 things missing (once fixed it works):

- You need to connect the `tableView` of the `TableTestTableViewController` to the `UITableView` you have on the screen. As I said before because it is not `IBOutlet` you can override the `tableView` property and make it and `IBOutlet`:

  ```
  @interface TableTestTableViewController : UITableViewController {
      UITableView *tableView;
  }

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
  ```
- Next thing is to add a reference to the `TableTestTableViewController` and retain it in the `TableTestViewController`. Otherwise your `TableTestTableViewController` may be released (after loading the nib with nothing hanging on to it.) and that is why you are seeing the erratic results, crashes or nothing showing. To do that add:

  ```
  @interface TableTestViewController : UIViewController {
      TableTestTableViewController *tableViewController;
  }

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TableTestTableViewController  *tableViewController;
  ```

  and connect that in the Interface Builder to the `TableTestTableViewController` instance.

With the above this worked fine on my machine.

Also I think it would be good to state the motivation behind all this (instead of just using the `UITableViewController` with its own `UITableView`). In my case it was to use other views that just the `UITableView` on the same screenful of content. So I can add other `UILabels` or `UIImages` under `UIView` and show the `UITableView` under them or above them.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent many hours pulling my hair out trying to figure out why a `UITableView` wouldn't show up when when I had it embedded in a separate nib instead of in the main nib.  I finally found your discussion above and realized that it was because my `UITableViewController` wasn't being retained!  Apparently the delegate and datasource properties of `UITableView` are not marked "retain" and so my nib was loading but the controller was getting tossed...  And due to the wonders of objective-c I got *no* error messages at all from this... I still don't understand why it didn't crash.  I know that I've seen "message sent to released xxx" before... why wasn't it giving me one of those?!?

I think most developers would assume that structure that they build in an interface builder would be held in some larger context (the Nib) and not subject to release.  I guess I know why they do this.. so that the iPhone can drop and reload parts of the nib on low memory.  But man, that was hard to figure out.

Can someone tell me where I should have read about that behavior in the docs?

Also - about hooking up the view.  First, if you drag one in from the UI builder you'll see that they hook up the view property (which is an `IBOutlet`) to the table view.  It's not necessary to expose the `tableView`, that seems to get set internally.  In fact it doesn't even seem to be necessary to set the view unless you want `viewDidLoad` notification. I've just broken the view connection between my `uitableview` and `uitableviewcontroller` (only delegate and datasource set) and it's apparently working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes for some reason (please chime in if anybody knows why...) `tableView` property of the `UITableViewController` is not exposed as an `IBOutlet` even though it is a public property. So when you use Interface Builder, you can't see that property to connect to your other `UITableView`. So in your subclass, you can create a `tableView` property marked as an `IBOutlet` and connect that.

This all seems hacky and a workaround to me, but it seems to be the only way to separate a `UITableViewController's` `UITableView` and put it somewhere else in UI hierarchy. I ran into the same issue when I tried to design view where there are things other than the `UITableView` and that was the way I solved it... Is this the right approach???

Comment: I wish I had better news but adding an IBOutlet-decorated tableView property to the Table View Controller and connecting it to the Table View in question didn't make any difference.  Very much appreciate the guidance though and I will keep updating here with any progress.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make this work.  I built a really nice dashboard with 4 TableViews and a webview with video.  The key is having the separate tableView controllers and the IBOutlets to the other tableview controllers defined in the view controller.  In UIB you just need to connect the other tableview controllers to the file owner of the view controller.  Then connect the tables to the corresponding view controllers for the datasource and delegate.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. I've removed the portion of your answer that isn't one.