# Separate UITableView Controller/Delegate Reference Quandary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been following the guide in the following ([StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254354/uitableview-issue-when-using-separate-delegate-datasource)), which has been very helpful, and by completing the steps I've managed to successfully have a UITableView with a separate controller and delegate/datasource.

However, even though everything is working, I'm unable to reference or change anything instance of the UITableview.

For example: let's say the UIViewController for the table is `TableViewController` and the separate delegate/datasource class is `TableDelegate`. I have everything hooked up in interface builder as in the previous SO question. In TableDelegate.m, within `viewDidLoad`, I put the following:

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`

And nothing changes in the UITableView as it should. This includes pushing UIViewControllers, which also has no effect as if the code wasn't even there, although when I `NSLog()`, it appears it is being run.

The odd part, however, is that even though that doesn't work, if I set the table's alpha property to 0, it works.

Thanks for any help in advance, let me know if you need any more information to solve the problem.

Comment: Is the `TableDelegate` a `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: It's a `UITableViewController` subclass.

Comment: So, both `TableDelegate` and `TableViewController` are `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` subclasses?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm puzzled nothing is working.

Comment: Are they both being added to the navigation stack?

Comment: How so? I'm not sure how to verify that.

Comment: In order words, are both being pushed to a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`?

Comment: TableDelegate and TableViewController should NOT both be subclasses of UINavigationController if you are using them together. That makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: TableDelegate is just that- a delegate & datasource for the table view. Therefore, it isn't being pushed to a `UINavigationController`, at least it shouldn't be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like both `TableViewController` and `TableDelegate` are subclasses of `UIViewController`. If this is the case, make sure both are being added to the navigation stack by pushing them onto a `UINavigationController` or adding them to a `UITabBarController`: otherwise, `viewDidLoad` may not be called.

As an aside, I don't think it's a good idea to have your `UITableViewDataSource` be a `UIViewController` subclass when you've already got a `UITableViewController` to handle that table view.

Comment: I would go so far as to say it's an absolutely terribly idea. Either have your delegate be the UIViewController or make it derive from NSObject

Comment: @Andrew Grant: Since the delegate/datasource isn't the File's Owner (UIViewController) in this case, it derives from NSObject as a `UITableViewController`. However, the problem still isn't fixed as I'm unable to change anything about the UINavigationController of the table view from the `TableDelegate` file.

Comment: @Chromium, you should make `TableDelegate` derive from NSObject and set it to conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols instead of `UITableViewController`. A `UITableViewController` is a view controller, and is supposed to be pushed to onto a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: @conmulligan: I understand your logic- however, how can I implement things like `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and pushing views onto the stack, if it's not a view controller?

Comment: You could reference the `TableViewController`'s navigation controller and push views onto that, but that's messy. At the very least, `TableViewController` really should be the `UITableViewDelegate`; is there a good reason why it isn't?